# Adding libxml2 to Xcode Errors

Tags: search, header, libxml2, kissxml

I've seen like 10239218301 other questions about this but NO solution has worked for me.

I've tried "Other Linker Flags" = `-lxml2`

I've tried "Search Header Files" = `$(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2`

I've tried "Search Header Files" = `$(SDK_DIR)/usr/include/libxml2`

I've tried "Search Header Files" = `/usr/include/libxml2`

I have tried all combinations of those with "Always Search User Paths" checked and unchecked.

I am trying to get it to xcode to work with KissXML but I have some 860 errors and 400 warnings...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incase anyone else is looking to solve this, I could not get the files off of the kissXML GitHub to work, but I downloaded the project from the following link and copied over the kissXML files.  It worked with the "$(SDK_DIR)/usr/include/libxml2" format.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project